# Git always automatically pushes tags even when `push.default=nothing` is set

Tags: git

I never understood why a simple `git push origin feature/bla` also tries to push `tags` which are not on the remote.

Here I am pushing on a remote `mruz` (a collaborators PR):

```bash
git -c push.default=nothing push --no-verify mruz install-fix

Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Delta compression using up to 32 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 628 bytes | 628.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 2 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To https://github.com/mruz/Githooks.git
 ! [remote rejected]       prepare-v2.8.0 -> prepare-v2.8.0 (permission denied)
 ! [remote rejected]       v2.3.0 -> v2.3.0 (permission denied)
 ! [remote rejected]       v2.5.0 -> v2.5.0 (permission denied)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/mruz/Githooks.git'
```

and it tries to push `tags`? Why is that and how can I disable this behavior?
The `-c push.default=nothing` does not work.

I am confused on how to disable this autmatic tag pushing behavior.

Comment: not even `git push --no-tags` works, It still pushes tags.

git version: 2.43.1

Answer (score -1):

Set `push.followTags = false` to disable permanantly.